# Set sequence for Union queries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgresql and trying to solve this:

I have 3 union queries. First query gives a single date, second queries gives id of a dealer and third prints its transaction. 
I want the date query to execute first and then the dearler id query.
How can i achieve this in postgres?
I tried doing this using sql using setOrder function

eg given below

```sql
select *\date query\*
union
   select *\id query\*
union
   select *\trnsaction query\*
```

When I execute this query all gets mixed up.

Comment: This sounds like a wrong use of `UNION`. Hard to say without the actual queries posted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to preserve the order of the individual queries is to add some additional "sort index" to each.

```sql
select *
from (
  select ...., 1 as sort_index
  from ..
  union all
  select ...., 2
  from ..
  union all
  select ...., 3
  from ..
)
order by sort_index, ...;
```